# Where is the data race with imread and cvtColor?

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv

According to ThreadSanitizer, I have a data race in the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>  // cv::imread
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>    // cv::cvtColor, cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV

int main() {
  cv::Mat img = cv::imread("img.png");
  if (img.empty()) {
    std::cout << "failed to read image" << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }

  cv::Mat imgHSV;
  cv::cvtColor(img, imgHSV, cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV);

  return 0;
}
```

Here's the result of running the code.

```
$ ./bin/main
==================
WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: data race (pid=10930)
  Write of size 8 at 0x7b2000000100 by thread T5:
    #0 operator delete[](void*) <null> (main+0xdf7b7)
    #1 <null> <null> (libtbb.so.2+0x23236)

  Previous read of size 8 at 0x7b2000000100 by thread T2:
    #0 memcmp <null> (main+0x97cd0)
    #1 <null> <null> (libtbb.so.2+0x214a4)

  Thread T5 (tid=10936, running) created by thread T2 at:
    #0 pthread_create <null> (main+0x9235a)
    #1 <null> <null> (libtbb.so.2+0x206e0)

  Thread T2 (tid=10933, finished) created by main thread at:
    #0 pthread_create <null> (main+0x9235a)
    #1 <null> <null> (libtbb.so.2+0x206e0)
    #2 __libc_start_main <null> (libc.so.6+0x27b24)

SUMMARY: ThreadSanitizer: data race (/home/user/bin/main+0xdf7b7) in operator delete[](void*)
==================
ThreadSanitizer: reported 1 warnings
```

This is how I'm compiling.

```
clang++ -std=c++17 \
    $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4) \
    -O1 -g -fsanitize=thread -fno-omit-frame-pointer \
    -fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow,null,alignment \
    -fno-sanitize-recover=null -fsanitize-trap=alignment \
    -Wunused-value -Wshadow \
    -o bin/main main.cpp
```

I'm on Arch Linux, using `opencv 4.5.4-6`.

Comment: Are you sure that's the exact line you're using? I see that you compile from `main.cpp` to `main`, but you execute `./bin/main`. Also, `-g` does not seem to generate line numbers even for `main.cpp` for some reason.

Comment: I meant to type `-o bin/main` in the description. Fixed the typo. Not sure why `-g` doesn't generate line numbers, is there something I can change to get the line numbers?

Comment: Are these races "normal" opencv behavior? I just tried compiling and running: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/d9e/fld_lines_8cpp-example.html and got hit with a wall of ThreadSanitizer warnings. 

Comment: I suppose they are either "normal" or tsan's false positives. They're not really inside OpenCV, more like in Intel TBB.